# What is configuration(Number of CPU, Memory) for each node in Bigtable cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

What is configuration(Number of CPU, Memory) for each node in Bigtable cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Each cluster in a production instance has 3 or more nodes, which are compute resources that Cloud Bigtable uses to manage your data.
You should [monitor your clusters' CPU and disk usage](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/monitoring-instance#cpu-and-disk), and [add nodes](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/modifying-instance#nodes) if you exceed the recommendations and limits.

So your cluster should in an ideal world handle the workload provided by your application, the nodes are the compute resources that google cloud dedicate to your bt cluster. You can monitor the workload and add node if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Afelaia !!! i already checked page pointed by you before raising question here. I was curious why there is no CPU and memory information anywhere in the Bigtable documentation. Do you have information about that?

Comment: If you already checked the relevant [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/monitoring-instance#cpu-and-disk), then you will know that tablets can be reassigned to different nodes in your cluster on demand, allowing Cloud Bigtable to scale and rebalance seamlessly as your usage patterns change. As reads and writes in your table increase, Cloud Bigtable might split into two nodes, in order to isolate hot rows and improve performance. Therefore, Google takes care of the configuring and tuning, you solely need to use it and monitor its resources as mentioned above.